# Air Conditioner: Panel Malfunction

Tags: repair, air-conditioning, appliances, diy-vs-pro

I have an old window A/C unit which the electronic panel is malfunctioning.
Basically, it keeps changing randomly the settings ([watch the video](https://streamable.com/uk8s0)). Examples:

- If I set the fan to low, after a while it might switch to high (and vice-versa).
- If I set to energy save, after a while it might switch to turbo.
- Sometimes I can't turn it on or off, although I can hear the 'beep' from the panel.
- ... etc ...

Besides that, it is working fine (ie: it can cool down the room).

Recently I called a technician to repair this unit. He said that this unit is too old to find spare parts and the most cost effective solution would probably be to buy a new one (unfortunately, buy a new one is not an option for me).

**Question**
Any idea how to repair this unit?

---

#### Additional Notes

**Air Conditioner description**

- Model: Springer Mundial Eletrônico
- Type: Window
- Capacity: 10500 BTU/h cold only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if a board starts acting "squirrely" like that, it's bad and they are not repairable. But in many cases it's not that hard to replace the entire board. Get the model number of your unit and do an internet search for a "main board" for it. If your unit is popular, you may find it for sale and in fact you may find a YouTube video showing you how to replace it. I have done that recently for two different electronic based appliances, both repairs were simple and inexpensive (compared to replacing the entire appliance).

Comment: > _"if a board starts acting "squirrely" like that, it's bad"_ Indeed, this is bad news. I though there were a chance to be only a simple stuff repair (ex: bad connection among the buttons).

Comment: Possible, but in most cases the "buttons" are surface mounted and soldered directly onto the printed circuit board, the thing you push on the front panel is just a plunger going to that button. It helps facilitate high speed mass production of appliances.

Comment: > _"the "buttons" are surface mounted and soldered directly onto the printed circuit board"_ If it is just a matter of unsoldering the old button and then solder a new one, doesn't seem to be very difficult. Maybe I could do it. At least seems to be worth a try.